# How to get the last name from the string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following string.

```
var str = "\\Desk-7\e\cars\car1.jpg";
```

I want to get `car1.jpg`. How can i get that using jquery or javascript

Comment: Is that your actual string... or did you mean to escape the backslashes?

Comment: Do you define the string like that or do you get a string like that? If you define it like that the result would be `"\Desk-7ecarscar1.jpg"`

Comment: @Anton you are correct if str is defined like that. Some escaping characters are missing

Comment: The string is coming from the controller. I am returning the filename form controller. There is no issue with chrome or safari or ff. The file is returning like this in ie only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can be done by

```
function basename(path) {
 return path.replace(/\\/g,'/').replace( /.*\//, '' );
}
```

Answer (score 6):

NOTE: str should be: `var str = "\\\\Desk-7\\e\\cars\\car1.jpg";` if hardcoded in code

```
var car1 = str.split('\\').pop();
```

Comment: +1 for cuteness, but, out of interest, is there a cheaper way of doing this? In C++ (and Java) we can get the position of a final occurrence of a character and substring from that. Saves creating an container object.

Comment: @Bathsheba lastIndexOf() used with substring() but less readable

Answer (score 2):

Or could be done with:

```
var str = "\\\\Desk-7\\e\\cars\\car1.jpg";
var name = str.slice(str.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

use str `.split('\\')` and then the last index

Answer (score 1):

first split then get it

```
var abc[] = str.split("\\")
var name = abc[abc.length-1];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"\\Desk-7\e\cars\car1.jpg".match(/\b[^/]+$/);    //["Desk-7ecarscar1.jpg"]
```